# Database change notification is not working when updated by JDBC query

Tags: java, oracle11g

Database change notification is not notifying when a row is updated by JDBC but when i update using SQL developer it is getting notified. Any reason?

Comment: are you committing your transaction/query while using JDBC?

Comment: It was working fine but suddenly it stopped working. Any idea what wud be the cause?

Comment: yes i commit. The changes are getting reflected in database

Comment: i am not an expert in this area, but have you tried the troubleshooting tips described here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_dcn.htm

Comment: yes i checked but am not able to find any solution

Comment: IN oracle community i see that this issue is faced by some other users, but there is no solution to fix this.https://community.oracle.com/thread/2493479?tstart=0

Comment: It is strange, even SQLDeveloper uses JDBC. If it is not something trivial then you should contact Oracle support.